# Gulp 4 выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, npm

**Исходники:** [Gulp4.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yVR5nF-agyPiEfrE4PhXRXaagRSjnVKy/view?usp=sharing)

**Ошибка:**

```
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (E:\Web\test\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (E:\Web\test\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web\test\gulpfile.js:224:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

**Версия Gulp:**

```
PS E:\Web\test> gulp -v
[06:20:13] CLI version 2.0.1
[06:20:13] Local version 4.0.0
```

**Версия Npm:**

```
PS E:\Web\test> npm -v
6.5.0
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "html-ready",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Devinora",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "gulp-terser": "^1.1.6",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp.spritesmith": "^6.9.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^6.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^6.5.0"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  watch = require('gulp-watch'),
  plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
  prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  babel = require('gulp-babel'),
  terser = require('gulp-terser'), //альтернатива gulp-uglifyes
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
  fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
  cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
  rimraf = require('rimraf'),
  browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith'),
  reload = browserSync.stream;

var path = {
  dist: {
    html: 'dist/',
    php: 'dist/',
    js: 'dist/js/',
    css: 'dist/css/',
    img: 'dist/img/',
    fonts: 'dist/fonts/'
  },
  app: {
    html: 'app/*.html',
    php: 'app/*.php',
    js: 'app/js/main.js',
    jsInit: 'app/js/init.js',
    style: 'app/scss/main.scss',
    sprite: 'app/img/sprite/**/*.*',
    img: 'app/img/*.*',
    fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*',
  },
  watch: {
    html: 'app/**/*.html',
    php: 'app/*.php',
    js: 'app/js/**/*.js',
    style: 'app/scss/**/*.scss',
    img: 'app/img/*.*',
    sprite: 'app/img/sprite/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*'
  },
  export: {
    img: 'app/img/',
    style: 'app/scss/imports/'
  },
  spriteTemplate: 'sass.template.mustache',
  clean: './dist'
};

var config = {
  server: {
    baseDir: "dist" // or ./dist
  },
  // tunnel: true,
  // host: "178.150.110.97",
  // notify: false,
  logPrefix: "Frontend_Devil"
};

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('html:dist', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.html)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
    .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('php:dist', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.php)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.php))
    .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('js:dist', function() {
  //init.js
  //Файл для инициации
  // gulp.src(path.app.jsInit)
  // .pipe(plumber())
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  // .pipe(fileinclude({
  //  prefix: '@@',
  //  basepath: '@file'
  // }))
  // .pipe(babel({
  //  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
  // }))
  // .pipe(terser())
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.babel-min', prefix : ''}))
  // .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))

  //Обычный js файл.
  gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
  //Babel-js файл.
  gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.babel',
      prefix: ''
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
  //Mini-js файл.
  gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(terser()) //альтернатива uglifyes
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min',
      prefix: ''
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
  //Babel-mini-js файл.
  gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
    }))
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.babel-min',
      prefix: ''
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
    .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('style:dist', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.style)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      sourceMap: true,
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(prefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min',
      prefix: ''
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
    .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('image:dist', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.img)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{
        removeViewBox: false
      }],
      use: [pngquant()],
      interlaced: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.img))
    .pipe(reload());
});

gulp.task('sprite:dist', function() {
  var spriteData =
    gulp.src(path.app.sprite)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(spritesmith({
      imgName: 'sprite.png',
      cssName: '_sprite.scss',
      cssFormat: 'scss',
      algorithm: 'binary-tree',
      cssTemplate: path.spriteTemplate,
      cssVarMap: function(sprite) {
        sprite.name = 's-' + sprite.name
      }
    }));
  spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.img));
  spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.style));
});

gulp.task('fonts:dist', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.fonts)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.fonts))
});

gulp.task('dist', [
  'html:dist',
  'php:dist',
  'js:dist',
  'sprite:dist',
  'style:dist',
  'fonts:dist',
  'image:dist'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  watch(path.watch.html, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('html:dist');
  });
  watch(path.watch.php, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('php:dist');
  });
  watch(path.watch.style, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('style:dist');
  });
  watch(path.watch.js, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('js:dist');
  });
  watch(path.watch.img, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('image:dist');
  });
  watch(path.watch.sprite, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('sprite:dist');
  });
  watch(path.watch.fonts, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('fonts:dist');
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['dist', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

**Частичное решение**

Проблема была в том, что при переходе на новый **Gulp 4**, не сделали обратной совместимости. Не знаю почему, и оправдано ли это, но ниже я приведу пример, который мне помог.

Они добавили два новых метода: `gulp.series`, `gulp.parallel`.

**Было:**

```js
gulp.task('dist', [
 'html:dist',
 'php:dist',
 'js:dist',
 'sprite:dist',
 'style:dist',
 'fonts:dist',
 'image:dist'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 watch(path.watch.html, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('html:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.php, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('php:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.style, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('style:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.js, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('js:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.img, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('image:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.sprite, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('sprite:dist');
 });
 watch(path.watch.fonts, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('fonts:dist');
 });
});

gulp.task('default', ['dist', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

**Стало:**

```js
//Удалил 

// gulp.task('dist', [
//  'html:dist',
//  'php:dist',
//  'js:dist',
//  'sprite:dist',
//  'style:dist',
//  'fonts:dist',
//  'image:dist'
// ]);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch(path.watch.html, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('html:dist');
 });
 gulp.watch(path.watch.php, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('php:dist');
 });
 gulp.watch(path.watch.style, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('style:dist');
 });
 gulp.watch(path.watch.js, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('js:dist');
 });
 gulp.watch(path.watch.img, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('image:dist');
 });
 gulp.watch(path.watch.sprite, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('sprite:dist');
 });
 gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('fonts:dist');
 });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel(
 'html:dist',
 'php:dist',
 'js:dist',
 'sprite:dist',
 'style:dist',
 'fonts:dist',
 'image:dist',
 'webserver',
 'watch'
));
```

**P.S:** На счет правильности написания  `gulp.task('watch')` я сомневаюсь, но такое решение мне помогло.

**P.S.S:** Это малая часть проблем. Буду благодарен, если отредактируете `gulpfile.js` так как нужно. Если нужны будет исходники, дайте знать.

```
[07:12:09] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[07:12:09] '<anonymous>' errored after 2.72 ms
[07:12:09] TypeError: gulp.start is not a function
    at E:\Web\test\gulpfile.js:227:8
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at asyncRunner (E:\Web\test\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Comment: Судя по первому стектрейсу у вас на 224 строке ошибка

Comment: Так,ответы - в ответы, а не в вопросы. Или это не ответ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, по началу это решило мою проблему, но вылезли другие ошибка. По этому я добавил исходники, и написал то, что смог решить сам.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, хорошо.

Comment: [Обновление Gulp до версии 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesyrCZE1bA&t=251s) посмотри видео про переход с gulp 3 на gulp 4, тут куча инфы, уверен что тебе поможет

Comment: @TigranVardanyan, я видел это видео, но она не решило мои проблемы в полной мере.

Answer (score 5):

В Gulp 4 изменили способ определения задач, если задача зависит от выполнения другой задачи, другими словами параметр списка `[]` для указания задач на выполнение - устарел.

У вас описан вотчер следующим образом (обратите внимание на `gulp.start`, его нужно будет заменить, так как запуск должен производиться иначе):

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  watch(path.watch.js, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('js:dist');
  });
  watch(path.watch.html, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('html:dist');
  });

  // some code here...

});
```

Вотчер нужно переделать так (вместо `start` используй `series`) :

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(path.watch.js, gulp.series('js:dist')); 
  gulp.watch(path.watch.html, gulp.series('html:dist'));

  // some code here...

});
```

Это примера запуска вотчера на JS и HTML (остальные по подобию). Единсвенное замечание - следите за правильностью указания пути к файлам в шаблонах (к примеру `'app/**/*.html'`).

Также переделайте запуск следующей таски (замените параметра списка `[]`):

```
gulp.task('dist', [
  'html:dist',
  'php:dist',
  'js:dist',
  'sprite:dist',
  'style:dist',
  'fonts:dist',
  'image:dist'
]);
```

К примеру на следующий код:

```
gulp.task('dist', gulp.parallel(
  'html:dist',
  'php:dist',
  'js:dist',
  'sprite:dist',
  'style:dist',
  'fonts:dist',
  'image:dist'
));
```

Далее, запуск `'default'` задачи, у вас он выглядит так (как писал ранее - параметр указания списка задач через `[]` - устарел):

```
gulp.task('default', ['dist', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Сделайте запуск `'default'` задачи вот так (чтобы они работали параллельно через `gulp.parallel`, также убрали запуск через параметр списка `[]`):

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('dist', 'webserver', 'watch'));
```

В Gulp 4 принято использовать вместо параметра списка `[]` следующие функции `gulp.series(...tasks)` и `gulp.parallel(...tasks)`.

По использованным функциям:

- `gulp.parallel(...tasks)` — запускает указанные задачи параллельно, при этом, если возникает ошибка, то выполнение будет завершено
- `gulp.series(...tasks)` — запускает задачи последовательно в указанном порядке, при этом, если возникает ошибка, то выполнение будет завершено

Ссылка на документацию по запуску задач внутри `gulp.series`:

- [Running tasks in series](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md)

Сссылка на похожую проблему и ее решение:

- [Everytime I run gulp anything, I get a assertion error. - Task function must be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51999610/5275890)

А также ссылка на гайд по переходу на Gulp 4:

- [A quick guide for switching to gulp 4](https://codeburst.io/switching-to-gulp-4-0-271ae63530c0)

Также, хочу обратить внимание на то, что все пакеты, которые вы используете в своем `gulpfile` необходимо обновить, обязательно удостоверьтесь в том, что они поддерживают Gulp 4. Про основные нюансы я рассказал, других проблем не должно возникнуть при переходе на Gulp 4, как правило основной проблемой является параметра списка `[]`, и иногда слишком старые пакеты.

---

Пример работы вашего приложения. Для начала, версии, которые установлены на моем компьютере (версии `node`, `npm`, `gulp`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого я запустил `gulp` и в браузере открылась страница:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я внес правки в `html` файл и сохранил изменения, при этом вотчер сработал и отобразилось в консоли изменение, также попробовал изменить `js` файл и в консоли эти изменения тоже отобразились:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере отобразились изменения практически моментально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, собственно сам `gulpfile` который я запустил:

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  watch = require('gulp-watch'),
  plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
  prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  babel = require('gulp-babel'),
  terser = require('gulp-terser'), //альтернатива gulp-uglifyes
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
  fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
  cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
  rimraf = require('rimraf'),
  browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  spritesmith  = require('gulp.spritesmith'),
  reload = browserSync.stream;

var path = {
 dist: {
  html: 'dist/',
  php: 'dist/',
  js: 'dist/js/',
  css: 'dist/css/',
  img: 'dist/img/',
  fonts: 'dist/fonts/'
 },
 app: {
  html: 'app/*.html',
  php: 'app/*.php',
  js: 'app/js/main.js',
  jsInit: 'app/js/init.js',
  style: 'app/scss/main.scss',
  sprite: 'app/img/sprite/**/*.*',
  img: 'app/img/*.*',
  fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*',
 },
 watch: {
  html: 'app/**/*.html',
  php: 'app/*.php',
  js: 'app/js/**/*.js',
  style: 'app/scss/**/*.scss',
  img: 'app/img/*.*',
  sprite: 'app/img/sprite/**/*.*',
  fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*'
 },
 export: {
  img: 'app/img/',
  style: 'app/scss/imports/'
 },
 spriteTemplate: 'sass.template.mustache',
 clean: './dist'
};

var config = {
 server: {
  baseDir: "dist" // or ./dist
 },
 // tunnel: true,
 // host: "178.150.110.97",
 // notify: false,
 logPrefix: "Frontend_Devil"
};

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
 browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
 rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('html:dist', function(done) {
 gulp.src(path.app.html)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
 .pipe(reload());
 done();
});

gulp.task('php:dist', function(done) {
 gulp.src(path.app.php)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.php))
 .pipe(reload());
 done();
});

gulp.task('js:dist', function(done) {
 //init.js
 //Файл для инициации
 // gulp.src(path.app.jsInit)
 // .pipe(plumber())
 // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 // .pipe(fileinclude({
 //  prefix: '@@',
 //  basepath: '@file'
 // }))
 // .pipe(babel({
 //  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
 // }))
 // .pipe(terser())
 // .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.babel-min', prefix : ''}))
 // .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 
 //Обычный js файл.
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 //Babel-js файл.
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(babel({
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
 }))
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.babel', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 //Mini-js файл.
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(terser()) //альтернатива uglifyes
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
 //Babel-mini-js файл.
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(babel({
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
 }))
 .pipe(terser())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.babel-min', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 .pipe(reload());
 done();
});

gulp.task('style:dist', function(done) {
 gulp.src(path.app.style) 
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(sass({
  sourceMap: true,
  errLogToConsole: true
 }))
 .pipe(prefixer())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
 .pipe(cssmin())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
 .pipe(reload());
 done();
});

gulp.task('image:dist', function(done) {
 gulp.src(path.app.img)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(imagemin({
  progressive: true,
  svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
  use: [pngquant()],
  interlaced: true
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.img))
 .pipe(reload());
 done();
});

gulp.task('sprite:dist', function(done) {
 var spriteData =
  gulp.src(path.app.sprite)
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(spritesmith({
   imgName: 'sprite.png',
   cssName: '_sprite.scss',
   cssFormat: 'scss',
   algorithm: 'binary-tree',
   cssTemplate: path.spriteTemplate,
   cssVarMap: function(sprite) {
    sprite.name = 's-' + sprite.name
   }
  }));
  spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.img));
  spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.style));
 done();
});

gulp.task('fonts:dist', function(done) {
 gulp.src(path.app.fonts)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.fonts))
 done();
});

gulp.task('dist', gulp.parallel(
 'html:dist',
 'php:dist',
 'js:dist',
 'sprite:dist',
 'style:dist',
 'fonts:dist',
 'image:dist'
));

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch(path.watch.html, gulp.series('html:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.php, gulp.series('php:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.style, gulp.series('style:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.js, gulp.series('js:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.sprite, gulp.series('sprite:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, gulp.series('fonts:dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('dist', 'webserver', 'watch'));
```

---

Поскольку некоторые задачи могут содержать асинхронный код, вы должны сигнализировать gulp, когда ваша задача завершит выполнение.

В Gulp 3 версий вы могли не делать этого. Если вы не указали явно асинхронное завершение, gulp просто предположил бы, что ваша задача является синхронной и что она завершена, как только ваша задача завершится.

В Gulp 4 был внедрен более строгий режим в этом отношении. Вы должны явно сигнализировать о завершении задачи. Это можно сделать пятью разными способами, о которых подробно описано в следующем ответе: [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36899424/5275890)

Самый простой способ - это вызвать функцию обратного вызова, которую Gulp автоматически передает вашей задаче в качестве первого аргумента. Нужно просто вызвать эту функцию в конце задачи (внес правку в ответ, в параметрах добавлена колбэк функция `done`).

Comment: Я сделал правки, но это не помогло. Вот [исходники](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p8L4pqM41XhdpZG_jRzYiQbtgdayTBep). Все что выше вы написали, по большей части я знал. Запустите мой проект, и вы увидите сами что не работает.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный у меня всё работает, прикрепил скриншоты работы приложения, скриншот с версиями, скриншоты запуска gulp, а также прикрепил сам `gulpfile` - только поменял секцию задачи `watch` так как у вас там везде был указан путь к `path.watch.js`

Comment: вы плохо тестировали работоспособность. Я вам [видео](https://youtu.be/YjbUMQWRMC8) снял для наглядности. прошу прощение за фон микрофона. Забыл его выключить и убрать шумы.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный попробуйте этот файл сборки https://yadi.sk/d/sVT7f7Gumo1f0w

Comment: @MaxManchak, вроде все заработало. я посмотрел ваши исходники, и увидел что вы используете `gulp.parallel` в таске `watch`. Я буду вам благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный та проблема, которую я не доглядел уже выходит за рамки вашего вопроса, однако я внес правку в ответ и пояснил причину такого поведения `Gulp`. Посмотрите в конце ответа про асинхронность (код в сниппете тоже исправлен, добавлена функция `done`)

Comment: Почему она выходит за рамки вопроса? Так как стандарт поменялся, то и код весь нужно было под него отредактировать, что собственно я и спросил. Просто ту ошибку, которую я предоставил, была вершиной айсберга. Вы мне предоставили код, который не работал, и оправдываете это тем, что это выходит за рамки вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ [Denis Bubnov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189339/denis-bubnov) актуальный, но я хочу предоставить свой конечный вариант.

Отдельное спасибо [Max Manchak](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300961/max-manchak), так как он в комментариях предоставил работающий код, и помог довести (*до совершенства*) конечный ответ.

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
 watch = require('gulp-watch'),
 plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
 prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
 babel = require('gulp-babel'),
 terser = require('gulp-terser'), //альтернатива gulp-uglifyes
 sass = require('gulp-sass'),
 sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
 fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
 cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
 imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
 pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
 rimraf = require('rimraf'),
 browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
 rename = require('gulp-rename'),
 spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith'),
 reload = browserSync.stream;

var path = {
 dist: {
  html: 'dist/',
  php: 'dist/',
  js: 'dist/js/',
  css: 'dist/css/',
  img: 'dist/img/',
  fonts: 'dist/fonts/',
  videos: 'dist/videos/',
  files: 'dist/files/'
 },
 app: {
  html: 'app/*.html',
  php: 'app/*.php',
  js: 'app/js/main.js',
  jsInit: 'app/js/init.js',
  style: 'app/scss/main.scss',
  img: 'app/img/*.*',
  sprite: 'app/img/sprite/**/*.*',
  fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*',
  videos: 'app/videos/*.*',
  files: 'app/files/*.*'
 },
 watch: {
  html: 'app/**/*.html',
  php: 'app/*.php',
  js: 'app/js/**/*.js',
  style: 'app/scss/**/*.scss',
  img: 'app/img/*.*',
  sprite: 'app/img/sprite/**/*.*',
  fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*',
  videos: 'app/videos/*.*',
  files: 'app/files/*.*'
 },
 export: {
  img: 'app/img/',
  style: 'app/scss/imports/'
 },
 spriteTemplate: 'sass.template.mustache',
 clean: './dist'
};

var config = {
 server: {
  baseDir: "dist" // or ./dist
 },
 // tunnel: true,
 // host: "178.150.110.97",
 // notify: false,
 logPrefix: "Frontend_Devil"
};

gulp.task('webserver', function(cb) {
 browserSync(config);
 cb();
});

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
 rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('html:dist', function(cb) {
 gulp.src(path.app.html)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});

gulp.task('php:dist', function(cb) {
 gulp.src(path.app.php)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.php))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});


gulp.task('js:dist', function(cb) {
 //init.js
 //Файл для инициации
 // gulp.src(path.app.jsInit)
 // .pipe(plumber())
 // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 // .pipe(fileinclude({
 //  prefix: '@@',
 //  basepath: '@file'
 // }))
 // .pipe(babel({
 //  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
 // }))
 // .pipe(terser())
 // .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.babel-min', prefix : ''}))
 // .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))

 //Обычный js файл.
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));

 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(babel({
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
 }))
 .pipe(rename({
  suffix: '.babel',
  prefix: ''
 }))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 //Mini-js файл.
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(terser()) //альтернатива uglifyes
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({
  suffix: '.min',
  prefix: ''
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
 //Babel-mini-js файл.
 gulp.src(path.app.js)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
 }))
 .pipe(babel({
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
 }))
 .pipe(terser())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({
  suffix: '.babel-min',
  prefix: ''
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});

gulp.task('style:dist', function(cb) {
 gulp.src(path.app.style)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(sass({
  sourceMap: true,
  errLogToConsole: true
 }))
 .pipe(prefixer())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
 .pipe(cssmin())
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
 .pipe(rename({
  suffix: '.min',
  prefix: ''
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});

gulp.task('image:dist', function(cb) {
 gulp.src(path.app.img)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(imagemin({
  progressive: true,
  svgoPlugins: [{
   removeViewBox: false
  }],
  use: [pngquant()],
  interlaced: true
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.img))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});

gulp.task('sprite:dist', function(cb) {
 var spriteData =
 gulp.src(path.app.sprite)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(spritesmith({
  imgName: 'sprite.png',
  cssName: '_sprite.scss',
  cssFormat: 'scss',
  algorithm: 'binary-tree',
  cssTemplate: path.spriteTemplate,
  cssVarMap: function (sprite) {
   sprite.name = 's-' + sprite.name
  }
 }));
 spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.img));
 spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest(path.export.style));
 reload();
 cb();
});

gulp.task('fonts:dist', function(cb) {
 gulp.src(path.app.fonts)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.fonts))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});

gulp.task('videos:dist', function(cb) {
 gulp.src(path.app.videos)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.videos))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});

gulp.task('files:dist', function(cb) {
 gulp.src(path.app.files)
 .pipe(plumber())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.files))
 .pipe(reload());
 cb();
});

gulp.task('dist', gulp.parallel(
 'html:dist',
 'php:dist',
 'js:dist',
 'style:dist',
 'image:dist',
 'sprite:dist',
 'fonts:dist',
 'videos:dist',
 'files:dist'
));

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch(path.watch.html, gulp.series('html:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.php, gulp.series('php:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.js, gulp.series('js:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.style, gulp.series('style:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.img, gulp.series('image:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.sprite, gulp.series('sprite:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, gulp.series('fonts:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.videos, gulp.series('videos:dist'));
 gulp.watch(path.watch.files, gulp.series('files:dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('dist', 'webserver', 'watch'));
```

Answer (score 0):

При переходе с gulp 3 на gulp 4 есть в принципе 2 проблемы, первая вроде как очевидная при первых попытка поиска решения проблемы: вместо массива с названиями тасков использовать метод gulp.parallel или gulp.series - между ними разница лишь в том, что метод .parallel запускает таски параллельно друг с другом, а вот метод .series не начинает выполнение второго таска указанного в нем до того как закончится первый...
итого можно использовать метод .parallel везде если нет строгой зависимости в чередности выполнения тасков переданных данному методу.

было:

`gulp.task('default', ['dist', 'webserver', 'watch']);`

стало:

```
`gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('dist', 'webserver', 'watch'));`
```

Вторая же проблема не такая очевидная, т.к. всё зависит от того как ранее настраивали gulpfile.

дело в том что таски в gulp представляют из себя поток, и если не "сказать" gulp, что поток завершен, то может вылезть ошибка.

Чтобы сообщить gulp что вызванный таск завершился есть 2 способа:

1) передать в параметры функции некий параметр (назовём его callback) и после выполнения всех действий вызвать этот параметр;

2) воспользоваться return для действий в таске.

на примере

было:

```
`gulp.task('html:dist', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.html)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
    .pipe(reload());
 });`
```

закроем поток таска использовав return:

```
`gulp.task('html:dist', function() {
  return gulp.src(path.app.html)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
    .pipe(reload());
 });`
```

предыдущий способ хорош, НО мы можем наблюдать в данном проекте таск js:dist, где мы не можем использовать return так как в таком случае прервется выполнение таска после выполнения первой задачи (т.к. return возвращает результат выполнения и дальше функция не выполняется):

```
`gulp.task('js:dist', function() {

   gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))

  //Babel-js файл.
  gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.babel',
      prefix: ''
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 //..... и далее другие задачи таска
});`
```

И вот в этом случае лучшим решением будет передать в параметры функции callback и вызвать его после всех необходимых нам действий:

```
`gulp.task('js:dist', function(callback) {

   gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))

  //Babel-js файл.
  gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.babel',
      prefix: ''
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
 //..... и далее другие задачи таска

callback();
});`
```

Comment: спасибо тебе за помощь. если бы ты раньше ответит, я бы тебе рейтинг присвоил)

Comment: Главное, что помогло))) а то сам когда столкнулся, потерял несколько часов чтобы понять почему ошибки выбивает))